# Sharing of partially applied functions

Tags: haskell, lambda, monads, sharing

I am currently experimenting with sharing of partially applied functions. In order to make sharing visible, I use the tracing effect. In order to illustrate my problem, I first show a [simplified example](https://gist.github.com/nbun/a601ed0a964ab08649775e83db4f88cf).

```hs
f1, f2, f3, f4 :: Int -> Int
f1   = \x -> trace "f1" 0 + x
f2 x = trace "f2" 0 + x
f3   = (trace "f3" 0 +)
f4   = (+) (trace "f4" 0)
```

I compare these functions in the following scenario, where `f1` is substituted by the different functions.

```hs
apply :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> Int
apply f g = f 42 + g 42

result = let f = f1
         in apply f f
```

The output (compiled without optimizations) is as follows.

```
f1 f1 f2 f2 f3 f4 336
```

The core code shows that both `f1` and `f2` are lambda functions, while `f3` and `f4` are partially applied functions. In the first case, there appears to be no sharing of the argument within the body of the lambda, while it works in the second case. Enabling compiler optimizations leads to sharing for all defintions, but I am interested in why there is no sharing within lambda functions.

Answer (score 5):

> I am interested in why there is no sharing within lambda functions.

There are some applications where you really do *not* want sharing. The classical example is if the value that would be shared is a lazy (and perhaps infinite) list. Then in a non-shared situation, the first use site may process this list in a stream-fashion, and the garbage collector can immediately clean up after it. The second user of the list will then need to re-do the list build computations, yes, but everything happens in *O*(1) memory.

*With* sharing, in this situation you keep a reference to the list root around, so the garbage collector would only kick in after the second user has also consumed the list. Maybe that happens much later, after the first user has already expanded the list to several gigabytes of size. You don't want that, in general! So, lambdas (CAFs) offer a way to prevent sharing in such situations. Only if the compiler determines that sharing is really beneficial in some situation, it optimises to share anyway.

> Is sharing of monadic computations for monad instances like `State` possible at all?

Y...yes it is, but I don't really understand what you want to share and how. Please clarify the question.

Comment: A point I usually make about sharing-by-default: as leftaroundabout says, sometimes you want it and sometimes you don't, but GHC has to pick one behavior. If it chose sharing-by-default, it would be very difficult to get the no-sharing behavior. Since it instead chose no-sharing-by-default, it is easy to get the sharing behavior if you want it: hoist the stuff you want to share out of the lambda. I think this may be what you were getting at near the end, but it wasn't totally clear to me.

Comment: That is helpful, thanks. I have removed the second part since it is unnecessarily complex. If I understand you correctly, you are saying that I can control whether sharing occurs by avoiding lambdas. My second example seems to boil down to something like this https://gist.github.com/nbun/ff6e2e3786f5f20bb6f9a3b67de1970d . In this situation, however, replacing  lambdas with the function combinator does not introduce sharing. What am I doing wrong here?